# Which is the best way to send server-side generated data on realtime to client in flask?

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I'm newbie programming web applications with flask and I need to show in a dashboard some information generated in real time on the server-side and display it in the dashboard asynchronously on the client-side.

I have been looking for information but I am a little confused because I see that it can be done by many ways, and I´m looking for some answer that could guide me to know which is the most efficient and simple way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what you have tried so far based on that we can help, please check how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example a question on SO.

Comment: Thank you @ArvindMaurya I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way for achieving what you need, is to open a websocket and start pushing data from to the server to the client. The client will then read the data whenever it is there, and show it to the user.

What's a websocket? See the following link for a good description on how to instantiate a client-side websocket connection.

https://javascript.info/websocket

As example for javascript, use

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

To implement the transmission, you will need a server capable of receiving websocket requests. You may use

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Otherwise, you may request the server for the latest data from the browser, e.g. every 5 seconds, and push the response to what you are displaying. This is much simpler, although, you would be asking continuously the server for data, even if there is none. You can implement it via a simple ajax call on the client side, and as (rest) api on the server side.

Comment: Let me know if I shall add more

Comment: No more information is needed :-), I have implemented the solution by sending the data to the client using socketio emits and on the client side a javascript script that collects the information sent by the socket and displays it. I really appreciate your help, I was a little lost and thanks to the information and the conceptual explanation I managed to get it up and running in 3 hours.